Making navigation.navigate() with params act like navigation.goBack() in a react navigation drawer
I'm using react navigation drawer (v6.x) and I have the following history of navigation.
ScreenA -> ScreenB -> ScreenC
However, when going back from ScreenC to ScreenB I need to pass some params. This isn't possible using navigation.goBack(). If I do use navigation.navigate() I can pass the params, but the issue is that when back on ScreenB, pressing back again will get me back to ScreenC instead of ScreenA. This is because navigation.navigate() in a drawer doesn't seem to replace the route in the history (like it does in a Stack navigator), it pushes a new one.
How could I proceed?
I was thinking to pass a callback function using navigation.navigate() an set the params there (Like in this article). This seems to work, but react-navigation documentation strongly advises against passing non-serializable values. A warning even appears in this sense.
Another one is to nest stack & drawer navigators, but this also creates other problems.

If you dont use gesture navigation and if ScreenA is always shown before ScreenB, a possible solution could be to use navigate('ScreenA') instead of goBack() on ScreenB.
Edit: you could also look into resetting the navigation state

I am using gesture navigation.
Resetting was a thought, but I found no way to preserve all the params passed in  all other screens.
